# Autohide in Dash to Panel on Ubuntu with GNOME

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

How can I enable auto hide in Dash to Panel? My GNOME Shell version is 3.28 and the version of Dash to Panel is 9999 as it says in the about page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Tweaks (install it using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`, if you haven't already).
2. Go to *Extensions* and click the gear icon next to *Dash to Panel* to open its settings.
3. At the bottom of the settings window you will find the *Panel Intellihide* option. You can enable this to make the panel intellihide (hide only when obstructed by another window) or click the gear icon to select another hiding option.

   [image: Dash to panel settings]

Comment: Don't see Intellihide on mine.  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, GNOME 3.28.2, and Dash to Panel 9999.

Comment: @BrentBaccala It should be there. The screenshot in my answer was from my 18.04 installation.

Comment: any chance you've got a newer version of Dash to Panel installed in your `.local`?  I tried installing the newest version (40) from the plugin's webpage and then was able to see the Intellihide feature.  Come to think of it, "version 9999" seems pretty strange.  The Ubuntu package version is 13, which is more in line with a current version of 40.

Comment: @BrentBaccala I suppose that the version that you had previously installed was cloned from GitHub. Here is a relevenat thread from the project's GitHub: https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/319 In short, version 9999 is used so that users that installed the extension from GitHub won't get constantly notified that a new version is available.

Comment: How do I get dash-to-panel on ubuntu 22.04?